# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' when using numpy.linalg.slogdet()

Tags: python, typeerror, natural-logarithm

I am trying to calulate `val` but I get a type error.

This is a small part of matrix used in the calculation to show the data type it contains, original matrix is 30x30.

```
covM = [[ 9.81431930e-02, -6.94931008e-03, -1.28573646e-02],
       [-6.94931008e-03,  5.28292692e-02,  6.23429384e-03],
       [-7.04098766e-03,  2.64439715e-04, -8.66008123e-04]]
```

To find `val` I calculate:

```
val = math.sqrt((2*pi)**30*np.linalg.slogdet(covM))
```

But get this:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

When I try using the normal determinant instead of the log it works fine:

```
val = math.sqrt((2*pi)**30*np.linalg.det(covM))
```

Why does this error occur with slogdet() but not det() and how can I make it work for the log determinant?

Comment: You get an error because [`slogdet`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.slogdet.html) returns two values, sign and det log. If you already know (or don't care about) the sign of the determinant, then you can use `np.linalg.slogdet(covM)[1]` to get only the log of its absolute value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `np.linalg.slogdet()` returns value two values, the sign of the determinant and the log determinant. I needed to specify the sign.
So to get absolute values I did:

```
val = math.sqrt((2*pi)**30*np.linalg.slogdet(covM)[1])
```